# Any recommendation for explanations for the verification key in ZK-SNARK?

Tags: reference-request, elliptic-curves, cryptography

I've read dozens of articles that are not math-heavy and got a pretty good grasp on the general idea of ZK-SNARK but I have not found many good articles on verification keys. Wonder if anyone can recommend some?

I am currently in front of "Succinct Non-Interactive Zero Knowledge
for a von Neumann Architecture" and "Pinocchio: Nearly Practical Verifiable Computation". I think they have detailed explanations for the verification key but are quite math-heavy. Wonder if there are any articles that explains verification key with less rigor but still convey the basic math ideas. Thanks!